# After running git bfg the file still shows up in my history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I followed the instructions here http://naleid.com/blog/2012/01/17/finding-and-purging-big-files-from-git-history, which I found very useful.

I had removed a 100 MB file when switching my repo to github, and I now want to remove other files that should probably have never been committed. After running these commands, the largest file is still listed, the one that I deleted.T here are false positives (files that show up as large but have been deleted). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify the exact commands you're using? Your question title says 'git bfg', perhaps a reference to http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ ? However, the naleid.com blogpost you link to isn't using The BFG, it's using git-filter-branch, which is a different tool.

Comment: @RobertoTyley Instead of the git filter-branch, I used bfg to remove the files as described at http://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/  I believe the exact command was "java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders myfoldername" followed by the garbage collection commands shown by bfg post. When I pushed to origin, it was pretty clear that the files had been changed based on the size of the commit. However, running all of the blog post commands again still showed the files. Is there a way to not included deleted files in the blog post commands?

Comment: We've had a similar experience, trying to remove directories that have already been made separate repos. We found that after all was said and done the repo size only shrunk by a fraction and we could still find commits involving the directories we thought we'd removed.

Comment: @PhysicalEd that seems to be about what I'm dealing with. I guess it is unavoidable.

Comment: What I found is that if you run BFG often enough (and this can easily be over a dozen times), the files or folders disappear eventually. Why, it beats me. Perhaps the author should focus more on this issue than to add political propaganda to the code.